# How do you determine heap/non-heap size for your Java microservices with Docker?

Tags: java, docker, microservices, amazon-ecs

We are running Java microservices in AWS ECS. So for Docker we are specifying some hard Java heap limit with -Xmx. It's a very tricky part to determine how much memory we can leave for heap and how much we need for non-heap memory(metaspace, stack, JIT cache, etc). *Currently, we are running a stress test to identify when we have Docker OOMKiller*. 
For example for 2GB AWS task(docker), maximum we can set -Xmx1400m for heap(with -Xmx1450m we don't have enough memory for non-heap stuff(Exit Code137))
Actually, Java 10+ has "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage" but we still need to know this percentage.

**How do you determine heap/non-heap size for your Java microservices?** Or the stress test is the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Java 8u131, [there is an option to set the JVM limits based on container memory limits](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits).  So if you run something like:

```sh
docker run \
  -m 2g \     # set a container memory limit
  openjdk:8 \
  java \
    -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions \
    -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap \
    com.example.Classname
```

the JVM will set the heap limit so that it fits within the 2 GB container memory limit, running `-Xmx` for you.  This should in principle arrange things so that you never hit the container memory limit but instead get a Java `OutOfMemoryError` first.

[This blog post](https://blog.csanchez.org/2017/05/31/running-a-jvm-in-a-container-without-getting-killed/) has a couple more examples on the topic, and also suggests `-XX:MaxRamFraction=1` to allow using "all memory", where you've limited that with the `docker run -m` option.

In practice you'd probably set `$JAVA_OPTS` in a Dockerfile like

```sh
FROM openjdk:8
COPY app.jar /
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRamFraction=1
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

and then run it like

```sh
docker run -d -p ... -m 2g myimage
```

In a Kubernetes environment, the declared memory limit in a pod's resource constraints plays the same role.

As @KarolDowbecki suggests in their answer, you do need to do some profiling and monitoring to actually pick a correct number for this.  Running the application locally and monitoring the `RSS` (resident set size) statistic in `ps` or `top` should give you a reasonable baseline.

Comment: Hi David, yor are right, for Java 8.131+ we can prevent Docker Killer, but we stll have Java OOM. 
We have to know how much memory we need for non-heap memory

Answer (score 2):

Running a benchmark is probably the right approach, however in practice doing it for every microservice that you have can prove very costly. On one hand without the benchmark it's impossible to guess how the microservice behaves under load e.g. will reduced memory increase the request processing time due to GC. On the other however RAM is relatively cheap comparing to developer's time and writing  benchmarks for distributed systems is frankly hard.

I don't believe that there is no formula to calculate this on paper. The answer would depend on each microservice implementation and usage. It has to be a constant cycle of testing and monitoring, if a problem is discovered then memory settings should be adjusted to resolve it.

Generally investing in monitoring should yield better returns than writing a suite of benchmarks.